# Inverted Partial Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $v = t +r+
ln(r−1)$, where $t$ and $r$ are independent of one another. Taking $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ or $\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}$ is straightforward enough, but if I wanted $\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}$ or $\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}$, would it suffice to write  $t$ in terms of $r$ and $v$ (or $r$ in terms of $t$ and $v$), and differentiate that with respect to $v$, or is something else required?

Comment: The notation for partial derivatives is unfortunately ambiguous. In taking $\partial v/\partial t$ one takes the derivative in $t$ at $r$ fixed, and the last piece of information is omitted from the notation.
Therefore, if $\partial t/\partial v$ means the derivative at $r$ fixed, then yes, it is enough to express $t$ as a function of $v,r$ and take the partial derivative with respect to $v$, at $r$ fixed.
Apart from the caveat of understanding what is really meant by the partial derivatives, what you say seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is hard to explicitly express a variable of a function as the other variables.

You can view this equation as a surface equation. Locally, when we fix any two variables, the third one is determined. $\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}$, for example, is the rate of change of $r$ on the surface along the axis $v$. We can view $r$ as an implicit function of $v, t$ ($v,t$ are independent from each other), and differentiate with respect to $v$ on both sides of the equation, i.e., using implicit differentiation and chain rule, to obtain the partial derivative in terms of $t, v$. Same argument apply to $\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}$.

Comment: So, in this case, when doing chain rule and implicit differentiation on the right side of the $r$ equation, I would have to add a $\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}$?

Comment: I guess I'm just asking because when solving for $t$ it looks like $\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}$ would just be $1$.

Comment: If you are using implicit differentiation to calculate $\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}$, $t, v$ are viewed as independent variables, so $\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}=0$ while doing the calculation. But when you are looking for $\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}$, you are viewing $t, r$ as independent variables, so $\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}=0$. Moving everything except $t$ to the left hand side, you will get $\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}=1$.

Comment: Oh, I see, that makes sense. Thank you.